# Migrated app to v7 now get this error when launching on iOS simulator: Cannot read property 'mainScreen' of undefined

Tags: nativescript

I just updated tools to v7 and migrated app.
Now when I run on emulator, I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mainScreen' of undefined.

I constructed the constant:

```
const screen = require("tns-core-modules/platform").screen;
```

and call it as normal:

```
screenWidth: screen.mainScreen.widthDIPS,
```

but autoComplete will not recognise .mainScreen property.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In Nativescript 7 all modules start with `@nativescript/...` scope.

And `screen` war renamed to `Screen`

You have to use new import and naming

```
const screen = require("@nativescript/core/platform").Screen;

const screenWidth = Screen.mainScreen.widthDIPs;
```

Comment: I searched for hours to find this...many many thanks!!! Not a single hint on the official page https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/platform#usage